# Confusion on Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to put 6 employees in 4 identical offices if at least one employee
must be assigned to each office?

So my thinking was put a person in each office and the last office gets the extra two people, therefore the number of ways is $\binom{6}{3}$.

The other set up is putting two people in the first two offices and the last two we put an extra person in there. So the number of wasys is $\binom{6}{2} \cdot \binom{4}{2}$, but this is incorrect. The right answer is: $\binom{6}{2} \cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$.

Why is the $\frac{1}{2}$here?

Comment: Because the ${6 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}$ overcounts, since it is possible to choose Bob and Sharon from the 6 and then Tom and Julie from the remaining 4, or to choose Tom and Julie from the 6 and Bob and Sharon from the 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the (1/2) here.

Because of overcounting.

Person-1, Person-2 in one office, Person-3, Person-4 in another office is counted **twice**.

Once when Person-1, Person-2 are the first two selected out of the 6, and once when Person-3, Person-4 are the first two selected out of the 6.

**Remember**, the offices are construed to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

We can take it as a division of $n$ number of different objects in $m$ different groups, where some group sizes repeats.
When no size repeats then usual formula is $\dfrac{n!}{a!b!...x!}$, where $a+b+..+x=n$. It is basically total permutation divided by permutations inside each group. But when some group size repeats then we need to consider their order, suppose size $a$ repeats $\alpha$ times then we need to divide further by $\alpha !$
For this case the first possibility as you wrote is forming groups of size $(3,1,1,1)$ for which we get initially $\dfrac{6!}{3!1!1!1!}$, but here size 1 repeats 3 times so the final number should be $\dfrac{6!}{(3!1!1!1!)(3!)}$ the next possibility of forming groups is of size (2,2,1,1), In this case the final number is $\dfrac{6!}{(2!2!1!1!)(2!2!)}$. Size 2 repeated twice, size 1 also repeated twice.